# Авто нажиматель submit для tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, html, css, userjs

Хочу сразу предупредить, что я никогда даже не начинал учить javscript, css и все такое прочее. Однако легенда вот какая: есть сайт, каждые 5 минут кнопка становится активной и ее надо отслеживать обновляя страницу, затем нажимать. Но кнопка эта не простая, а форма, в одном из инпутов которой передается ID, а другой -  submit:

```
<div class="app-fuel__cin">
<form method="post" action="/givefuel">
<input type="hidden" name="_xsrf" value="тут ID">
<input type="submit" class="button button-left" value="Givefuel">
</form>
</div>
```

Получил из похожего скрипта вот такой:

```
var timewait = 16;
var givefuel = document.getElementsByClassName('button button-left')
setTimeout(give, 0);
var i = 0;
function give(){
    for(var is = 0; is < givefuel.length; is++){
        givefuel[is].click();
    }
    setTimeout(reloadpage, timewait*1000);
}

function reloadpage(){
    location.reload(true);
}
```

И проблема в методе getElementByClassName, который, судя по тому что я нагуглил, использовать вообще не получается ибо button.button-left там не одна и используются они по разным назначениям. Как поступить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой вариант должен сработать. У меня всё сработало.

```
function goJS(interval){

            var a = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //ищем инпуты на странице
            for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){

                if(searchJs(a[i])){
                    break; //если нашлась нужная нам кнопка, ломаем цикл
                }else{
                    if(i==(a.length-1)){
                        setInterval("location.reload()",interval); //если нужной кнопки не нашлось - перезапускаем через указанные n миллисекунд
                    }
                }
            }

            function searchJs(arg){
              /* Если надо вписать что-то в input hidden

                if(arg.type == "hidden" && arg.name == "_xsrf"){
                    arg.value = "JS is VERY COOL!!!";
                }
              */

                if(arg.type == "submit" && arg.value == "Givefuel"){
                    arg.click(); //жмем на кнопку
                    return true;
                }

                /* Если нужно именно по классам
if(arg.getAttribute("class")=="button" || arg.getAttribute("class")=="button button-left"){
                   arg.click(); //жмем на кнопку
                   return true;
                 }
                */
            }
        }
        goJS(3000); //Запускаем скрипт с обновлением каждые 3сек
```

Comment: А вот это работает, большое спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

браузер FF или Chrome ? вот так мб...

```
document.querySelector('.app-fuel__cin input.button.button-left').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Comment: Заменил
document.getElementsByClassName('button button-left') на этот вариант, страница не обновляется, по кнопке не кликает, последний хром.

Comment: а там много этих кнопок ? если много то надо как-то так http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/D3rJg/

Comment: К сожалению, на кнопку по-прежнему не кликает